# Getting "unsupported format string passed to NoneType. __format__" error

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm getting the unsupported format string error message from the following code;

```
title = print("SCHEDULE")
                                                                
print(f"{title: >50}")
```

I've done this countless times before without any issues, strange how it's coming up now? Am I being completely blind to something?

I tried to above, as I have done many times before, but only now getting the error.

Comment: Your code is not valid python at all. Please fix it so that it can be run and the error is reproduced.

Comment: How so? I had a typo in the post, have removed a '

Comment: Yes that was how so.

Comment: Still getting the error message. The typo was only in this post...

Comment: title is `None` after this line: `title = print("SCHEDULE")` What do you expect the next line to do? What are you trying to print?

Comment: print doesn't return a value. You're first line is not doing what you are expecting.

Comment: I thought I was assigning printing "SCHEDULE" to the variable but I can see what I've done now - I didn't need it to say print on that line. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function doesn't return anything. Therefore `title` is `None`.

The raised error is because a `NoneType` (in this case the value the `title` variable holds) can't be formatted (it's not a `str` as I suppose you'd like).

Try `title = "SCHEDULE"` without printing.